# is it possible to combine grep -C or -A or -B with something that EXCLUDES the matching line

Tags: linux, grep

So with grep we can use -A to get lines "after" the match, we can use -B to get lines "before" the match. Also we can use -C to get lines both before and after.

I have some data like this

```
boring data
boring data
boring data
interesting value
MARK
boring data
boring data
boring data
interesting value
MARK
```

I'd like to get output like this:

```
interesting value
interesting value
```

With the option -B I get this:

```
# cat somefile | grep -B 1 MARK

interesting value
MARK
interesting value
MARK
```

I'd like to exclude the MARK lines entirely.

Answer (score 10):

You can add an inverse `grep` with `-v` after your first `grep`:

```
$ grep -B1 --no-group-separator 'MARK' somefile | grep -v 'MARK'
interesting value
interesting value
```

I added `--no-group-separator` to omit the separator lines between matches.

Comment: Very similar to the common `ps -aef | grep iTunes | grep -v grep` method commonly used to pick out a process ID *without accidentally picking up the process you're using to look for it*.

Comment: One way around that is `... | grep '[i]Tunes'` -- that will match the process named "iTunes" but not the grep's parameter "[i]Tunes"

Answer (score 8):

If you are not tied to using `grep`, then you can use other tools, such as awk.

```
awk '/MARK/ { print saved_line }
     { saved_line=$0 }'
```

which says to print the saved line if the line is matched, and on every line to save it in case it is needed again.